# Configuration vs Database storage

Tags: database, configuration, web-config

I will keep this short, I am looking to store product plan data, these are the plans that the users would pick for their payment options. This data include how much the plan cost and what the unit details of the plan are, like what makes a unit (day/week/month) and fairly simple data about the plan. These plans may or may not change once a month or once a year, the company is a start up and things are always changing on the 11th hour and contently so there is no real way to predict when they will change. A co-worker and I are discussing whether these values should be stored in the web.config (where they currently are) or move them to the database.

I have done some googling and I have not found any good resource that help draw a clear line of when something should be in the database or in the web config. I wanted to know what your thought on this was and see if someone could clearly define when data should be stored in config or in the database.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the brief description you provide, it seems to me that the configuration data, *eventually*, may be accessed not just by your web server-based application running on one computer, but also by other supporting applications, such as end-of-month batch jobs, that you may want to run on other computers. To support that possibility, it would be a good idea to store the data in some sort of centralized repository that can be accessed remotely from multiple computers.

Storing the configuration data in a database is the obvious way to meet that requirement. But if you don't want to do that, then another approach would be to store the configuration data in a file on a company-internal (rather than public) web/ftp server. Then an application can use a utility such as [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to retrieve the configuration file from the web/ftp server.

Of those two approaches, I think using a database is probably best, because it provides an ergonomic way to not just read the configuration data, but also update it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeah that was part of the downfalls of the web.config approach is there are so many areas these plans have to be updated whenever one changes. This is in the transform files as well as in the unit tests configs and such. I was thinking database but you helped describe another good reason why database. Thanks :)